# Perl File::NFSLock fails to acquire lock with error EACCESS

Tags: multithreading, perl, locking, nfs

I have a file on an NFS mount which is locked and unlocked for every operation done on it.
Initially I used `flock(filehandle, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)` but that attempt failed with `I/O Error`.
On browsing through multiple forums I found a solution to use `File::NFSLock` to lock/unlock files on a NFS share. However, NFSLock succeeds on the first attempt to lock and unlock the file, however when 2 processes simultaneously tries to access the locks, it fails with `EACESS` error.
Here is how the code is:

1. `Process 1` acquired lock with the below code and also released the lock once done:

```
    if ($lock = new File::NFSLock {
      file      => $handle,
      lock_type => LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB,
    }) {
```

2. Now 2 processes were spawned with a `fork` command (`Process 2` and `Process 3`). When `Process 2` tried to lock the same file using same above code in Step 1, file locking failed with error `Permission Denied`. After 15 seconds when `Process 3` tried to acquire lock it also failed with `Permission Denied` error.
   When I executed `fuser -v` on the file, I could see 2 process IDs (`Process 2` and `Process 3`) which had opened the file for writing.

Few documents on internet suggest that `The lock cannot be set because it is blocked by an existing lock on the file. Some systems use EAGAIN in this case, and other systems use EACCES` however doesn't seem to be the case in my scenario as `Process 1` had released the lock.
Also please note that all the 3 processes were spawned from the same script, so there shouldn't be an issue of different user trying to acquire the lock.

Thank You!

Comment: Please provide the complete error message. `new File::NFSLock` doesn't produce the error message you provided.

Comment: Here you go - 
[Couldn't open "FileHandle=GLOB(0x800ac68).tmp.2810.31272.5622" [Permission denied]]

Comment: 1) If the question needs clarification, it should be edited. 2) You're passing a file handle instead of a file path for the `file` parameter. Maybe not only problem, but first problem. 3) In bed now.

Comment: The same code works for one process and not for others.. so I doubt that can be a problem, anyways let me try with the path and update it.

Comment: Re "*Few documents on internet suggest that The lock cannot be set because it is blocked by an existing lock on the file.*", This is not relevant; the module doesn't try to set any locks

Comment: Hey @ikegami, the savior, replacing the handle with path worked .. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm surprised that was it, but awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File::NFSLock expects a file path —not a file handle— for its `file` parameter. Replacing the file handle with a file path solved the issue.

```perl
if ($lock = new File::NFSLock {
  file      => $path,             # Previously, I used file handle here.
  lock_type => LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB,
}) {
```